# How to change the file that will be open when npm start command is given?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, directory, package.json

I am learning react.js for the first time and in the course I follow instructor instructs to install Node js and configure it using the `npm init` command which creates a package.json file. Then the instructor told us to install lite-server which is a nodeJs sever according to him. This installation was also recorded in the package.json file. Then he told us to add the below line of code to the package.json file.

```
"main": "index.html",
```

A file named index.html was created previously.
and then another line of code which looks like,

```
"start": "npm run lite",
```

I understand the actions these lines perform. The package.json file and the index.html files are located in the same directory. The problem is when I try to put index.html file into a subdirectory named HTML, and change `"main": "index.html",` to `"main": "html/index.html",` and type `npm start` command, and error "cannot GET" shows in the browser page. That's the only thing that is displayed on the page. How can I change the entry point to a file in a subdirectory?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.
Change
"main": "html/index.html"
to
"main": "./html/index.html"
the ./ tells nodeJS "in the same directory".
Then, it sees "oh html/index.html in the same dir? Ok now I'll go to the html folder and Voila!"
That's not what it actually says but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: maybe try an absolute path? Such as "C:\Users\yourname\Documents\html\index.html"

Comment: Just remembered one more thing, there are 2 slashes, back and forward, maybe switching it makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I also recently started learning react and from my understanding you want to locate the "scripts" section in your package.json file. You should see something like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  // ...
},
```

you want to change this to

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start --entry ./html/index.html",
  // ...
},
```